# Figuring out what Photo Stream is uploading exactly

Tags: photos.app, photos, data-transfer, photo-stream, aperture

Even though I have unchecked the *Automatic Upload* of Photo Stream on Aperture (same on iPhoto), I can see through Little Snitch that it is hogging my upload bandwith constantly.
When I wait (hours, days..) to see what was uploaded, nothing is added to my photo stream.

Is there any way to figure out live what is being uploaded?

*Here is what the Console returns when I block Photo Stream's outgoing connections:*

```
MSPublisher - 1307885906 Encountered temporary network issues during upload. Will try again later...
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Little Snitch does not monitor bandwidth, only connections, so I am not sure what you mean by Little Snitch showing you that "it is hogging my upload bandwidth". What exactly are you seeing in Little Snitch? A screenshot would be helpful. Also even if you disable Automatic Uploads, if Photo Stream is enabled at all, it will still check with the server for new *downloads* in the stream.

Comment: By "hogging my upload bandwith" I mean that I can see the Photo Stream process uploading constantly at the maximum upload rate available to me. Little Snitch does give you the current upload/download speed of your connection, and can also show you what address each process is uploading to or downloading from.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: What happens if you disable that connection? do you get error from photo stream, --check for it in your console.

Comment: @tubedogg done.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Where should I check for errors when I block it ?

Comment: In the Utility folder-- Console, look under all messages at the time stamp around the time you blocked it, then look for something about photo stream messages. That might tell you who and what is asking for.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I edited with the log message from the Console. This message is repeated a large number of times in the log.

Comment: Well done, good team work..now..the obvious question would be, do you have some kind of MS Publisher files on your Mac? honestly I do not know what that has to do with PhotoStream, oder than guessing that somehow your MSPublisher files are looking for downloads using photostream. Since Microsoft Publisher does not work with OSX I wonder what you have going on there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Don't know either what MSPublisher is, and no I do not have any kind of Microsoft Publisher files on my mac. I barely use any Microsoft technologies on my mac.

Comment: Figured out after letting it run for a while that it is indeed uploading (very large images), even though the Automatic Upload is off. I asked in a new thread here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100903/photo-stream-uploads-while-automatic-upload-unchecked

Comment: Microsoft Publisher is a publishing software (that does not work on mac), however you might have a MSPublisher converted file on your system and that one is looking for Internet stuff. At least it is what your Log shows. In the log you can ask for more information on that message.

Comment: OK, here is the theory.... you might have gotten a MSPublisher file in html format that has a imbeded active link, that one is looking for images on the web, using your photostream. The file could be in your email or other places.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I believe that MSPublisher is an object in the Core Media Stream frameworks located at `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework`. This is not likely related to the Microsoft Publisher desktop publishing software.

Answer (score 1):

If Aperture's activity window isn't showing you the file name of what is being uploaded then my suggestion is a bit terminal intensive (you've been warned).

$ sudo fs_usage | grep 'DSC_'

you can replace what's in the ' ' with the beginning of your image names or even the suffix of .jpeg or .nef or what have you. You should even be able to write 'Aperture' just make sure that Aperture isn't in the foreground because that will give you automatic outputs from window server displaying the application being drawn.

This will output a list updated every millisecond of what files are being touched. So close all other programs you don't need and let Aperture try to do it's thing and terminal print it out. Fingers crossed!